# How to make tomcat (url = ip:port) automatically go to my app instead of root file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I made a docker container which runs my webapp on a tomcat server.

When i want to open my webapp now I have to look for "ip:port/app".

Is there a way to make "ip:port" automatically go to my app instead of "tomcat successfully installed page"?

The dockerfile i have right now is:

```
From Tomcat:latest  
Copy web.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

I run the container with:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8080 image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default re-direction of the url :8080 to the app webpage will be handled at the tomcat level.

The below link would be useful to set the default page to app.

https://www.jvmhost.com/articles/how-to-override-tomcat-default-home-page/